# How to use users current coordinates in Onsensor changed method using geocoder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, geocode

I want to use users location coordinates to make a compass that point at another location coordinates. I some how managed to achieve the code but a problem occur I dont know how to use users location coordinates to on sensor changed method or how to call it

My main activity(Compass) code :-

```
public class Compass implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Compass";

    protected double bearing(double startLat, double startLng, double endLat, double endLng){
        double longitude1 = startLng;
        double longitude2 = endLng;
        double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(startLat);
        double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(endLat);
        double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
        double y= Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(latitude2);
        double x=Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longDiff);

        return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
    }

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        final float alpha = 0.97f;

        synchronized (this) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                mGravity[0] = alpha * mGravity[0] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[0];
                mGravity[1] = alpha * mGravity[1] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[1];
                mGravity[2] = alpha * mGravity[2] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[2];

                // mGravity = event.values;

                // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(mGravity[0]));
            }

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                // mGeomagnetic = event.values;

                mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[0];
                mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[1];
                mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - alpha)
                        * event.values[2];
                // Log.e(TAG, Float.toString(event.values[0]));

            }

            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                    mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (rad): " + azimuth);
                azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
                azimuth = (azimuth + azimuthFix + 360) % 360;
                azimuth -= bearing("USER LATITUDE HERE", "USER LONGITUDE HERE", 21.422487, 39.826206);

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onNewAzimuth(azimuth);
                }
                azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]); // orientation
                azimuth = (azimuth + azimuthFix + 360) % 360;

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onNewAzimuth(azimuth);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

    }

    public interface CompassListener {
        void onNewAzimuth(float azimuth);
    }

    private CompassListener listener;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor gsensor;
    private Sensor msensor;

    private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
    private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
    private float[] R = new float[9];
    private float[] I = new float[9];

    private float azimuth;
    private float azimuth2;
    private float azimuthFix;

    public Compass(Context context) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        msensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    public void start() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, gsensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, msensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    public void stop() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void setAzimuthFix(float fix) {
        azimuthFix = fix;
    }

    public void resetAzimuthFix() {
        setAzimuthFix(0);
    }

    public void setListener(CompassListener l) {
        listener = l;
    }
}
```